# bash - How to delete block of lines which length is given in another file and doesn't match patterns

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Say I have a pattern - file1 of this content

```
48     0      1000
50     0      3000
```

and file2 that I want to edit of the following content:

```
48     0      1000
bla
...
bla
49     0      2000
bla
...
bla
50     0      3000
bla
...
bla
```

Now, I want to delete lines that

1. do not match pattern
2. and all the following block lines which length is given by number in the third column.

So the result is:

```
48     0      1000
bla
...
bla
50     0      3000
bla
...
bla
```

and wc -l < result is 4002.

My idea is to take a loop through file2, start in the first line and take a loop through file1. If match, then move line marker over a number that is in column 3 nl=`awk 'NR==1{print $3}'`, if not delete sed -i 'lm,lm+$nl d' file2

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: Sorry, didn't want to offend anyone. My idea was to take a loop through file2, start in first line and take a loop through file1. If match, then move line marker over a number that is in column 3  nl=`awk 'NR==1{print $2}'`, if not delete sed -i 'lm,lm+$nl d' file2.

Comment: Comments are not the place for code. Please edit your question using the "edit" link under your question, and put these important parts of your question in the question itself.

Comment: I wrote a solution in Fortran. Is it ok to post it here?

Comment: by all means, I'm sure people will love to see a bit of Fortran! if I were you I would submit it as an answer to your own question. But you shouldn't tag it as "best answer" (with the green checkmark) since your question was about doing this in bash/awk/sed. Your green checkmark should go to the answer that best addresses the problems stated in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next;}/^([[:digit:]]+[[:blank:]]+){2}[[:digit:]]+$/{f=a[$0]}f' file1 file2
```

details:

```
NR==FNR {    # when the first file is processed
    a[$0]=1  # store each line in an array
    next     # jump to the next line
}
# file2: if a line has the format
/^([[:digit:]]+[[:blank:]]+){2}[[:digit:]]+$/ {
    f=a[$0]  # then set the flag f to a[$0] (1 if it exists, 0 if not)
}
f # when f is set to 1, print the line.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code in Fortran:

```
  nr = 0
  do
   read(1,*,iostat=io) i
   if (io/=0) exit
   nr = nr + 1
  end do
  rewind(1)
  allocate( I1(nr),I2(nr) )
  do j = 1, nr
    read(1,*) I1(j), I2(j)
  end do

   largeN = 10000
   nb = 0
   do
! Nbl...no. in the third column
   read(2,*,iostat=io) int1, int2, Nbl
       match = .false.
       do j = 1, nr
         if ( (int1.eq.I1(j)).and.(int2.eq.I2(j)) ) then
! avoid duplicities, change matched arrays to sth. that is not contained in columns 1 and 2 in file1
           I1(j) = largeN
           I2(j) = largeN
           match = .true.
! output in unit=3
       write(3,*) int1, int2, Nbl
         end if
       end do
       if (io/=0) exit
       nb = nb + 1
       do i = 1, Nbl
         read(2,*) x 
       if(match) write(3,*) x
       end do
     end do
  End
```